# Node-Red on windows, how to set the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED to 0

Tags: https, node-red

This is more for testing than anything, so yes I know the self-signed cert issue should be fixed.  I'm talking to the vendor about that already.  However - I can use the API properly in Python using requests and setting verify=False.  So - the API does work.

In Node-Red I get the error:  "RequestError: self-signed certificate in certificate chain".  I would like to use a module to change this prior to the call. Unsure how to do that.  I did try to make this entry in the settings.js file, but it did not help:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'
```

I set that before the module.exports location.

Comment: Maybe I fixed it... not sure yet as the parameters are not quite working yet.  But I no longer get the error after doing the following:

* In the http request node:  enable secure (SSL/TLS) connection
* Edit that connection, uncheck 'Verify server certificate'

Comment: How are you starting Node-RED? is it from comand prompt, Power Shell or something else? Also what is making the call, is it just a HTTP request node?

Comment: I start Node-RED with task scheduler under my own administrator.  it is an HTTPRequestNode, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a HTTP-Request node you should be able to disable certificate checking in the node it's self.

First in the http-request node, check the "Encable secure (SSL/TLS) connection" box, then click on the pencil to create a new tls-conf

[image]

In the tls-config, uncheck the "Verify server certificate" check box

[image]

This should get you what you need without needing to set the environment variable.

Comment: This is what I already did :)  So - yes, it is the solution (at least for me).  thanks for laying it out in this way, should help plenty of others.